# Javascript datetimepicker get value on change

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am trying to intercept changes to a WooCommerce Extra product options datetimepicker component. Essentially, it's just a datetimepicker.

I have:

```
<script>
    var box = document.getElementById("myDateTimePicker");
    //console.log("#devlog: Active");  

    box.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        var selectedDate = box.value;
        console.log(selectedDate);    
  });
</script>
```

Which is *almost* working. It outputs the previous value contained by the datetimepicker, not the value it has just been changed to.

I've tried a range of events in the eventListener but nothing seems to do the trick. Could some kind soul put me out my misery and clue me in to how to get the NEW value from the datetimepicker when it is changed? Thanks.

Update:

Here is the html from the form. The component I'm fighting with is the date-picker inside the last `<tr>`.

```
<form class="cart" action="http://blahblahblah:8888/product/191/" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="hidden" id="thwepof_product_fields" name="thwepof_product_fields" value="name_of_skater,tel_number,which_day" />
    <table class="thwepo-extra-options thwepo_simple" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="section-title">
                    <h3 class="">Mandatory information</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="label leftside">
                    <label class="label-tag ">Name of skater</label> <abbr class="required" title="Required">*</abbr></td>
                <td class="value leftside">
                    <input type="text" id="name_of_skater" name="name_of_skater" value="" class="thwepof-input-field validate-required">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="label leftside">
                    <label class="label-tag ">Telephone number</label> <abbr class="required" title="Required">*</abbr></td>
                <td class="value leftside">
                    <input type="tel" id="tel_number" name="tel_number" value="" class="thwepof-input-field validate-required">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="label leftside">
                    <label class="label-tag ">Pick a day <b>only</b></label> <abbr class="required" title="Required">*</abbr></td>
                <td class="value leftside">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="which_day" name="which_day" value="" class="thwepof-input-field thwepof-date-picker validate-required" data-readonly="no">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="quantity hidden">
        <input type="hidden" id="quantity_5e583e6ca4c48" class="qty" name="quantity" value="1" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="191" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to basket</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `onChange` event listener.

Comment: See if this works: 
box.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);    
  })

Comment: Weird. Tried both suggestions and still getting the previous value. Thanks though. Still trying....

Comment: Hmm. Post the answer when you get it because I'm curious what is going on.

Comment: Could we see HTML as well? Also, no jQuery solutions are allowed?

Comment: I have updated the main body of my question to include the html. The date-picker which I'm about to boot into orbit is the last <tr>. I'd rather not use jquery, if possible, thank you.

Comment: It only fails inside the eventListener. From the console if I do:

a = document.getElementById("myDateTimePicker");
a.value

It works and gives me whatever date the control is set to, even after just changing it. There is something about trying to do this from inside an eventListener that's breaking it and returning the previous value.

Comment: This reminds me of a quirk I've noticed using reactjs (It must be a js thing). When I try to set the state inside of an event, the function must complete before it is available. I think were are experiencing something similar. In my case, I would just set the state, and then use the value from the currentTarget object from within the function, then later on I could use the value from the state per usual. Not sure if there's a way you could do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
document.getElementById('myDateTimePicker').onChange = function() {
console.log(document.getElementById('myDateTimePicker').value);
}
```

You might be able to use `this.value`, but I wrote it the long way just in case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're a genius. Changing the onChange to just 'change' worked.

document.getElementById('which_monday').change = function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('which_monday').value);
    }

Big thanks to all who helped.